# Coverage.py returns error "No source for code:..." when running tensorflow.keras.model.fit function

Tags: python, unit-testing, tensorflow, keras, coverage.py

I have built unittests for my code and everything works fine when running them from vscode.   Even running `coverage run` runs successfully.
But when I try to run `coverage report` I get the following output:

```
No source for code: 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\1\__autograph_generated_file4ilniiln.py'
```

I found out that this happens exactly when I add a test case which contains `tensorflow.keras.Model.fit` function. If I remove `tensorflow.keras.Model.fit` then this message does not appear for `coverage report` command.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow rewrites your code and runs it from a new location.  I need some assistance to get it working properly in coverage.py.  See this issue for details: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/856

You can try using the `-i` flag to `coverage report` to ignore files it can't find. I don't know if you will still get complete data or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Reading your link (and referenced links in it), I came along `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)` which seems to work (at least for my cases).

Comment: Is your code public? I'd be interested in a reproducible case that I can experiment with.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not public available.